# spring boot call stored procedure [ConverterNotFoundException]

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to list all the employees by using stored procedure and My Requirement is to get all the details of an employee by calling the procedure.below is my code

## Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({@NamedStoredProcedureQuery( name ="Listall",
procedureName = "list_emp")})
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name="SALARY")
    private int Salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        Salary = salary;
    }

}
```

## My DAO IS

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer>{

    @Procedure(name ="Listall")
    public List<Employee> get_employee();
}
```

## Service

```
@Service
    public class EmployeeService {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepository Erp;

        public List<Employee> GetAll(){
            return Erp.get_employee();
        }

    }
```

## Controller

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/employee")
    public class EmployeeController {

        @Autowired
        EmployeeService eservice;

        @RequestMapping(value="/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<Employee> getAll(){
            return eservice.GetAll();
        }
```

while submitting the Get Request Getting the Follow Exception.

## The Exception

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.HashMap<?, ?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure com.pg.springboot.oracle2.entity.Employee]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToCollectionConverter.convert(CollectionToCollectionConverter.java:89) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:212) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:166) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RC3.jar:2.2.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RC3.jar:2.2.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RC3.jar:2.2.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RC3.jar:2.2.0.RC3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.get_employee(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.pg.springboot.oracle2.service.EmployeeService.GetAll(EmployeeService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.pg.springboot.oracle2.Controller.EmployeeController.getAll(EmployeeController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: As I cannot see your procedure, so can you provide it, the point is to define the IN/OUT parameter by using  `@StoredProcedureParameter`

Comment: My procedure Looks Like :                                                                                                 create or replace PROCEDURE list_emp IS
data employee%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO data from employee;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( SQLERRM );
END list_emp;